# Can't split polyline into 20 metre segments

Tags: qgis, error

I'm trying to make 20 metres segments out of one line, but I'm getting this error:

> segment outside line, no segment created

I'm using the settings shown in the screenshot. If I unblock the "force segments to be exactly of given lenght(...)" it works but then I get segments of 30 metres instead. The segments need to be 20 metres.

[image]

Comment: try to set the value of the segment to 0.00017998, the whole point is that they have established a geographic coordinate system ...

Comment: Do you mean the lenght or the v.in.ogr min area? I'm really new at QGIS, if you wondering why I'm asking rather dumb/strange questions.

Comment: я имею ввиду значения поля с названием "Maximum segment length" and never hesitate to ask questions, otherwise you will be hard to learn ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input line is in geographic coordinates CRS which uses decimal degree unit. you need to reproject the line and select a projection that uses meter unit such as UTM with the correct zone depending on the line location in which country.

To reproject the lines, right-click the line in the table of contents, go to `Export -> Save Features As`:

[image]

Click on the globe icon to choose the correct UTM zone, for example WGS 84 / UTM zone ## N/S, and give the file a new name.

Then use the output file in v.split tool to split the line at 20 m interval.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It solved my problem :)